# PGP encryption/decryption of a text file in salesforce

Tags: apex, javascript, encryption

I want to encrypt a text file with bank details and want some specific user or team can decrypt those with the private key. How to achieve this using PGP.

Answer (score 1):

Apex has no facilities to do PGP encryption or decryption, and it's unlikely that you'd be able to write your own implementation (which is a terrible idea in general) because the crypto support in Apex is very limited and the governor limits are restrictive.

Don't mess with cryptography unless you have expert-level knowledge of the math involved.

It sounds like you may want to look at [Shield Platform Encryption](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.security_pe_concepts.htm&type=5) instead.

Comment: Shield Platform Encryption won't accomplish the goal here IMOP

Answer (score 0):

In theory, you could store key pairs in a custom setting or custom object text field and use a JavaScript library in the browser with an LWC Component (https://github.com/openpgpjs/openpgpjs)

I can't remember if there is a limitation on using a JS library like OpenPGPJS in an LWC - I haven't tried it.

Otherwise, write a service in Java/Python/etc. and do a request & reply to encrypt/decrypt the messages.